# Instantiate and Add objects to a generic extension method

Tags: generics, ienumerable, instantiation

I am trying to create an extension method which will instantiate and add an object to a generic object list. I have a working example but the implementation is something I was wondering if it can be improved.

```
//This Append method works 100% fine
public static T[] Append<T>(this T[] source, params T[] toAdd)
{
    //if the item is null, make it new
    if (source == null) source = new T[0];

    //create the list and append
    var list = new List<T>(source);
    list.AddRange(toAdd);

    //return the list
    return list.ToArray();
}


//The implementation looks like this though
Object[] objArray = null;
objArray = objArray.Append(new Object());

//What I would like it to be is simply
objArray.Append(new Object());
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?